# How to share image/video on SnapChat from my iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, snapchat

I have used below code to open SnapChat and it only opens SnapChat from my app.

```
NSURL *appSnapChatURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"snapchat://app"];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:appSnapChatURL]) 
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appSnapChatURL];
}
```

**Now I need one more functionality that how to add text/image/video in that so I can share text/image/video on SnapChat from my app.**

Please help.

Comment: you can use UIActivityViewController in which you can pass video or image or text. That might help

Comment: Thanks, I attached image in below code then activity is showing SnapChat option... NSArray *objectsToShare = @[myImage];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: But when I am trying to attach a local video with code... NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"10Secs" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
NSArray *objectsToShare = @[fileURL];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil]; then activity is not showing SnapChat option, please help.

Comment: Can not share videos directly from UIActivityViewController to snapchat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208980/video-not-attached-for-mail-when-sharing-video-using-uiactivityviewcontroller

Try the way is getting the url of the video

Comment: If we can not share videos directly then how we can share videos to Snapchat. Please suggest. If any other way is possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144240/discussion-between-ali-farhan-and-asif-raza).

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sample text", nil];
    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    activityViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

    [activityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *act, BOOL done)
     {
         //Code here for completion handler
     }];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
       [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    //if iPad
    else {
        // Change Rect to position Popover
        UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:activityViewController];
        [popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 0, 0)inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks again, I am doing same as above. I have successfully attached image and it shares to SnapChat but when I am trying to attach video then activity controller is not showing Snapchat option.

Comment: My code is... -(void)showActivityWithURL:(NSURL *)url {
    
    NSArray *objectsToShare = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:url, nil]; //@[url];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
} Please help, how to attach video in activity. Or if possible, we can share video without using UIActivityViewController. Then it will be better. Thanks.

Comment: Actually there is no api available to share the video directly to snapchat as per my knowledge because snapchat closed their developer portal back in 2015

Comment: @AliFarhan but then how TicTok is able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

By using SCSDKCreativeKit --

```
   import SCSDKCreativeKit

  
   func shareToSnapchat(imageName: UIImage) {
    let stickerImage = imageName
    _ = SCSDKSnapSticker(stickerImage: stickerImage)
    let photo = SCSDKSnapPhoto(image: stickerImage)
    let photoContent = SCSDKPhotoSnapContent(snapPhoto: photo)
    
    photoContent.caption = "Anubhav Singh"
    photoContent.attachmentUrl = "https://twitter.com/anubhavpulkit"
    
    snapAPI.startSending(photoContent) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            // success
        }}
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Snapchat share in iOS, Swift. Please follow the tutorial below.

[Snapchat Creative Kit iOS (Swift) - Image, Video, Sticker Sharing](https://mahmudul-razib.medium.com/snapchat-creative-kit-ios-swift-image-video-sticker-sharing-8ec8ed7e5efd)